# How to render this Angular component with PHP / HTML

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, angular, apache

I'm involved in multiple PHP/HTML/Javascript projects everyday and normally I'm in rush with most of them having to do small changes quickly and in an easy way.

I'm interested to use the Angular/Material components in some of them.

For example the following: `select` component.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#resetting-the-select-value

Here is the source code:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kkgkroxexny?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="State">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

What options do I have to use these components in an easy way? Maybe by using this component tag like any other HTML tag and with the support of normal Javascript to specify the list of states? This list is provided by PHP and its content changes often depending on some conditions. In other words, it is not a fixed list.

I cannot use NodeJS in this context because I'm using Apache/PHP. Also, I'm not a fan of using V8 to render Javascript on the server side with PHP.

For example, the following is an example of what I wanna achieve (check source code):

https://zeuscronos.github.io/angular-material-multiple-components/datepicker.html

The problem is that the above example is a way to use **Angular 1** and it doesn't work with **Angular 2**. I wanna achieve something similar for **Angular 2**.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Angular components aren't really designed to be randomly dropped into other pages.

Comment: check material-design.lite